# Why does the integral of 1/x from negative infinity to infinity diverge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm confused as to why
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx$$
diverges. If $\frac{1}{x}$ is an odd function shouldn't the area to the left of origin be the opposite of the area to the right of origin, resulting in a net area of 0?

Comment: Both "areas" are infinite. $1/x$ is not integrable in any neighborhood of zero because of its singularity there. You *can* define something called the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral, which is zero.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @user135330  Even if you replace the $x$ by and $x^2$ the integral still diverges. Do you see why?

Comment: @imranfat Yes because 1/x^2 goes to infinity at x=0

Comment: @user135330 yep :)

Answer (score 3):

As an improper integral, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx = \lim_{N \to \infty}  \int_{-N}^{ - \frac{-1}{N}}\frac{1}{x} dx + \lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{M}}^{M}\frac{1}{x} dx$

Comment: Technically, even that is a simplification, since the limits of each of your two integrals should vary independently, so there should be four limits in all.

Comment: Could it be something like this $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-1}  \frac{1}{x} dx + \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{1}{x} dx +  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx$ ?